# Unable to retrieve specific fields from a text file in bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, text-files, bulkinsert

I have the following lines in a text file delimited by "|". I only want to retrieve the Surname and Firstname and write it into a table.

```
Released_Date|Label|Type|Id|FormId|Title|Surname|First_Name|Middle_Name
25/07/2014|XCS|CDE|V000011|F000011|Miss|Dālwó|Cabĉver|Ann
25/07/2014|XCS|CDE|V000011|F000011|Miss|Rtyālwó|sabĉper|Joanne
```

I created the XML file to retrieve only the Surname and firstname:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Surname"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="First_Name"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And I create the stored procedure to read it:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.ImportTextFile
AS
BULK INSERT test FROM 'C:\Program Files\Data Import.txt'
WITH 
  (
     FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',
     ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',
     FIRSTROW =2,
     FORMATFILE = 'C:\Program Files\cabcolumns.xml'
  );
```

There are no errors but the problem is the whole row from the text file gets inserted into the two columns of the table but I want only the Surname and First_Name. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have also given the DDL of the table below. Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
[Surname] [nvarchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI NULL,
[First_Name] [nvarchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: for both fields in the XML you set `\n` as terminator. maybe that's the culprit? if the terminator is the newline then the whole row is the field's content.

Comment: @Paolo I tried using "|" as the terminator but it gives an error "An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the issue is in the terminator in the XML file and in the numbering of the source columns.

first test could be a quick update to change field terminator on a sample of data (as a test, to understand if the terminator itself is an issue) updating all the configuration files accordingly.

ruled out the terminator issue, reading [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) you can find an example on how to skip columns when importing data (notice the filed ids):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Surname"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="First_Name"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

then to import:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.ImportTextFile
AS
BULK INSERT test FROM 'C:\Program Files\Data Import.txt'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FORMATFILE = 'C:\Program Files\cabcolumns.xml', LASTROW = 3);
```

explicitly setting the number of the last row you can avoid issues should the last line be empty or the system having troubles correctly detecting the end of the data.

Comment: Tried this. but getting this error:                                                    Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ImportTextFile, Line 3
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ImportTextFile, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ImportTextFile, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: please see my edit about the import parameter `LASTROW` and on the XML.